# How do I allow a user access to one specific directory and its contents?

Tags: permissions

I am using Ubuntu Server 11.04, how can I make it so a user can only access `/var/www/site1`?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe `chroot` or something.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/ftp-server.html

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure but `sudo chown -R a_user /var/www/site1` might work.

Or if you want any other users to access the directory and its content `sudo -R chmod 744 /var/www/site1` might help.